# Shouldn't the following code be executed after turning off the interrupt?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

This is the code of function `kthreadd` from linux 4.19.
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19/source/kernel/kthread.c#L559

```
int kthreadd(void *unused)
{
    struct task_struct *tsk = current;

    /* Setup a clean context for our children to inherit. */
    set_task_comm(tsk, "kthreadd");
    ignore_signals(tsk);
    set_cpus_allowed_ptr(tsk, cpu_all_mask);
    set_mems_allowed(node_states[N_MEMORY]);

    current->flags |= PF_NOFREEZE;
    cgroup_init_kthreadd();

    for (;;) {
        set_current_state(TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);
        if (list_empty(&kthread_create_list))
            schedule();
        __set_current_state(TASK_RUNNING);

        spin_lock(&kthread_create_lock);
        while (!list_empty(&kthread_create_list)) {
            struct kthread_create_info *create;

            create = list_entry(kthread_create_list.next,
                        struct kthread_create_info, list);
            list_del_init(&create->list);
            spin_unlock(&kthread_create_lock);

            create_kthread(create);

            spin_lock(&kthread_create_lock);
        }
        spin_unlock(&kthread_create_lock);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I think that following code should be executed after turning off interrupts.

```
        set_current_state(TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);
        if (list_empty(&kthread_create_list))
            schedule();
        __set_current_state(TASK_RUNNING);
```

If not, thread could fall asleep even though `kthread_create_list` is not empty.
Think of the case where thread is scheduled out by timer interrupt, right after setting thread's state `TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE`.

We need to wake it up again to do what we want.

I think this is weird.

What did I miss?

Comment: wow. I heard that after an interrupt, scheduler activates. You mean that scheduler doesn't work if the stat is "TASK_INTURRUPTIBLE". What if the state is "RUNNING"? Thread is preempted?

Comment: (My previous comment wasn't quite right, so I deleted it). A thread in `TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE` state is NOT a sleeping thread. So if a thread will be preempted in such state, it is still runnable and can be selected by the scheduler again. Only when a thread in TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE state calls (by itself!) `schedule()`, the thread goes into the sleep and becomes to be non-selectable by the scheduler. So the only case when `kthreadd` puts the thread into the sleep is emptiness of list `kthread_create_list`.

Comment: Thanks so much. It seems that state written by ```set_current_state``` is different from the state which is used by a scheduler. ```schedule``` actually change the state which is used by a scheduler to ```Interruptible```.

Comment: It's hard to believe but it explains well. Thank you so much. Have a nice day :)

Comment: thank you thank you. You're right. Only ```schedule``` deques the run queue and scheduling by timer doesn't trigger ```schedule``` nor dequeing. Thank you so much.